# Chronicle Queue: how to make a stack and how to limit disk usage

Tags: java, database

My server and several clients are different JVMs running on the same machine, they need to share persisted time series data: server reads a time series from somewhere, writes to a persisted embedded storage. Several clients then read the timeseries from that storage in the same order.

Chronicle Queue seems to be the best storage for this purpose: (0) embedded as a Java library, (1) persisted, (2) inter processes non-blocking communication, (3) has order.

The only 2 problems are: (1) I want a stack FILO order instead of a queue FIFO order (2) This whole system needs to run on a normal laptop thus I must need to limit the disk usage of the queue.

Any idea how ? Thanks

Comment: I have used RollCycles of Chronicle Queue to start a new file after every time-unit (minute, hour, day), and then I have been able to delete old files. However I want a limitation basing on the number of elements, not on time.